# why implementing interface's methods is same as overriding?

Tags: java, interface, overriding

i have stumbled on a definition lately that methods signatures dont need to be the same when some class is implementing methods from interface, like it happens in this example:

```
 Number doSomething() throws Exception;
}

class SomeClass implements SomeInf {

 public Integer doSomething() {
 return 1;
 }
}
```

I always thought that the return types and all of those things must be the same as an interface. Can you explain me why they don't need to be? It works as overriding methods but why it is made like this?

Comment: An Integer is a Number. When overriding a method, whether it comes from an interface or not, you can narrow the return type to a subtype. This is referred to as covariant return types.

Comment: `Integer` is a subclass of `number`.

Comment: Note that return type is not part of a [method's signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2).

Comment: However, [the return type is relevant to this question](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5).